# Leaving Multidex.install(this) when multidex=false in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

To enable multidexing I have following piece of code in my CustomApplication class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    MultiDex.install(this);
    // rest of onCreate method...
}
```

Now for this to work I need to set `multidex true` in build.gradle file for app. However, is there any problem with leaving this piece of code when do `multidex false` in gradle file? I.e. must I comment code out?

Or I can leave `MultiDex.install(this)` in code without any problems when my multidex is false? Will there be no side effects?

**EDIT:** I need this because during development I switch between multidex configurations. Also I have `multidex true` for some build flavors, and then `multidex false` for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can leave `MultiDex.install(this)` uncommented and set `multiDexEnabled false`. `MultiDex` will be disabled.

**Edit**

It won't cause a problem, <strike>but what is the point to keep it then?</strike>

Yes, You can!

Comment: Added explanation in question - thanks for your answer!

Comment: @kape123 ok I see what you mean, yes absolutely keep it, and as you set different configs to your flavors